# Invoking web service from a MultivaluedMap jax-rs

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have a web service that takes a client request and sends it to a second web service. It takes the response of second web service and sends it to the client. Actually it's a gateway. Type of request is "form urlencoded". The gateway takes the request from client as below:

```
@WebMethod
@POST
@Path("/send")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
String send(MultivaluedMap<String, String> encodedRequest, @Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest);
```

Now I have a MultivaluedMap and I want to invoke the second web service with this MultivaluedMap and without performing any process on it. The second web service consumes "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" too. Is there any way to invoke the second web service without performing any process on this MultivaluedMap?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you calling the second web service?

Comment: I made a string from keys and values of MultivaluedMap<String, String> and then I made a HttpURLConnection!

Comment: Why? You're using JAX-RS for the server-side part of your proxy, so why not use JAX-RS for the client-side part of your proxy, i.e. for the forwarding call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a POST request using JAX-RS [`Client`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html), you call [`buildPost(Entity<?> entity)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Invocation.Builder.html#buildPost-javax.ws.rs.client.Entity-), where `entity` is the POST content.

The [`Entity`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html) has many useful helper methods, e.g. [`form(MultivaluedMap<String,String> formData)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Entity.html#form-javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap-):

> Create an "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" form entity.

So, you write something like this:

```
Future<Response> response = client.target("http://example.com/foo")
                                  .request()
                                  .buildPost(Entity.form(encodedRequest))
                                  .submit();
```